# Component for progression with start and end value

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls, custom-component

I have to replay some animation.
I would like to find a component suitable to let me set a start time and end time, and display the progression of the remaining duration of the animation.
I was thinking of some mix between a slider with 2 buttons and a progress bar, but think this component is hard to design.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What UI are you using? Swing? SWT? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/) describes exactly what you need, it comes with full source code.

Comment: +1 @fpoilpret very nice link (booked). I think it answers to nearly all OP's needs, except maybe the progress display? None the less it is a great starting point.